# ¿Por qué no me funciona insertar imágenes?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, imágenes

Cuando intento añadir una imagen se abre la ventana y la veo "mal".

[image]

Uso Chrome 56

Lo que se ve no seria tan malo, pero no me funciona ni el `drag&drop` ni ninguna funcionalidad ...

¿Os pasa a alguno más? Veo que la gente sube fotos...

Comment: me parece que ví un reporte sobre el tema en inglés...

Comment: Sería necesario indicar desde que explorador tienes dicho problema, asimismo, si hiciste una prueba que el explorador no se vea afectado a extensiones (_navegar de forma privada_).

Comment: No puedo reproducirlo en mi Google Chrome 56 bajo Windows 10.

Comment: cierto, @davlio, ahora lo añado

Comment: @fedorqui yo 56 tambien pero en win7

Comment: lois6b: nótese que con _no puedo reproducirlo_ quise decir que a mí sí me funciona subir imágenes en ese entorno. Ahora en Ubuntu 16 y Google Chrome 57 me funciona todo menos pegar un vínculo de la web.

Comment: yaya, @fedorqui te entendí hahah

Comment: Intenta reproducir el problema con Chrome en modo de navegación privada (incógnito) con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas y nos cuentas que pasó.

Comment: @Rubén si funciona haciendo eso :O

Comment: Si requieres ayuda adicional, te sugiero crear una sala de chat. Por mi parte, hoy me va a ser casi imposible estar al pendiente, pero el fin de semana creo que si podré hacerlo. ¡Suerte!

Comment: @lois6b sería cuestión de realizar un descarte con tus extensiones instaladas, quizás hubo una actualización de una extensión que ahora genera el error.

Comment: @davlio eso hice y puse en la respuesta lo que me encontré. Un saludo y gracias  ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a los comentarios vi que era una de mis extensiones la que afectaba al comportamiento. (pero no la que decia Rubén).

Estuve quitando y probando extensiones hasta que descubrí cual era.

El fallo era con la extensión:

> ```
> cVim  (1.2.86)
> ```

No es muy común pero si alguno tiene un problema como el mio deberia mirar esa extensión.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un reporte sobre esto en [meta.se] -> [Image uploads not working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292019/image-uploads-not-working)

En la [revisión 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/292019/7) el OP agregó a la parte inferior de la pregunta que el problema se debe a la extensión de Norton para Chrome de la siguiente forma:

> **UPDATE:**
>   A Norton extension for Chrome was the source of the problem.

y como [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292021/289691) indicó que resolvió el problema inhabilitando la extensión:

> Disabling a Norton extension for Chrome (Norton Security Toolbar 2017.0.0.8) resolved the issue.

Comment: No creo que sea Norton (ya que no la tengo) ni otras extensiones porque no instalé ninguna nueva y esto antes me funcionaba